# Sencha app getting failed because of Failed creating background process and error occured

Tags: ruby, extjs, extjs5

Sencha app getting failed because of Failed creating background process and error occured.

My app was getting failed then on StackOverflow I found some answer which is all about change ruby. I tried couple of ruby versions but didn't get any luck with that.

I have ruby 2.2.2 installed and I am trying to build my app. I am getting following error. This is very annoying.

** This Failed after change ruby, and I change ruby because of the next error**

BUILD FAILED [ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExProcess: Failed

> creating background process [ERR] java.io.IOException: Cannot run
> program "ruby" (in directory
>
> "C:\User\MasterBuild\trunk\1\1\1\1\AppName\build\temp\production\AppName\sass"):
> CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

And these are the actual error.

> [ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
>
> C:\1\MasterBuild\trunk\1\1\1\1\AppName.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:284:
> The following error occurred while executing this line:
>
> C:\1\MasterBuild\trunk\1\1\1\1\AppName.sencha\app\sass-impl.xml:155:
> The following error occurred while executing this line:
>
> C:\1\MasterBuild\trunk\1\1\1\1\AppName.sencha\app\sass-impl.xml:176:
> com.sencha.exceptions.ExProcess: Failed creating background process

Can anyone please give some suggestion how to fix that. Thanks for all help.

Comment: Which version of Sencha Cmd are you using? Why you have Ruby 2.2.2 ?  Did you installed ruby using the standard installer? https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ Make sure that it's added to your path

Comment: As far as I remember Cmd prior to version 6 was dependent on Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: @pagep my ruby was correct only and after some answer I changed ruby and then again revert it back with same manner. I am using extJS 5

Comment: @Emissary I am using extJS 5 and same ruby was working for around 1 and half years for me

Comment: @David you are using ExtJS 5, but your Sencha Cmd version can be different. They are backwards compatible - so you should be able to build your app with Sencha Cmd 5 or 6 - and these versions might have different dependencies.